# How can i extend Depedency Injection in an Action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On `startup` i have setup my action filter.

```
services.AddScoped<CheckThisAttribute>();
```

The action filter itself is

```
public class CheckThisAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Context Db;
    private readonly string Name;

    public CheckThisAttribute(Context context, string name = "")
    {
        Db = context;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and consumed on controller via

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckThisAttribute))]
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

As you may have noticed, i have set the `name` parameter at the constructor as optional.
If i don't i will get runtime errors. (The context is passed via DI, but name doesn't)

Can i extend this action filter, so i can pass also the `name` from my controller?
Something like

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckThisAttribute(name="Something")))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that result with `ServiceFilterAttribute`.

Instead try the `TypeFilterAttribute`, which will look like this:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(CheckThisAttribute),
    Arguments = new object[] { "Method 'Hi' called" })]
```

Here is the doc's link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1